# How do I change onclick to open in same window?

Tags: html, button

hoping someone can help me with this. I have a very basic HTML page with a form using the POST method, with the action linking to a php file.
I have a button on the form. I want to write the code such that, when a user clicks on the button, they are redirected to another page (and their inputted data is also posted to the php file).
I'm *almost* there with the following code (I know it's a bit hack-y, but at least it's simple):

```html
<form method="post" action="form_data_processor.php">
<input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter your email address" /><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="window.open('login_thanks_page.html')">Log In</button>
```

But of course, it opens in a new window! Is there a way to have it open in the same window?
(I've tried using window.location.href, but for some reason that simply redirects to the php file which then appears as text on the webpage).
Any advice greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: window.location.href = URL

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, your approach isn't the one you should actually do.

In your `form_data_processor.php` you should actually redirect to the desired page:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/login_thanks_page.html');
exit;
```

This allows you to redirect differently, if the outcome isn't the one desired (password wrong, ...)